# after i turn my ATI graphics card off,when i suspend my session then i can't log in again[session]

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, suspend

I've Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I've turned graphics card off as it was producing a lot of heat.
-Now when I suspend my session then I can't log in again.When I click the power light gets on but the screen remains blank and I can't start the new session.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, starting the x-server will work

Alt + Ctrl + F2 (opens Command Line Interface)

Log-in

```
sudo startx
```

Comment: I have tried but it's not working..

Comment: you can see it here ubuntu1up:                            http://planetoss.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/

Comment: Wow! You can use nano in the Command line interface and delete your edits to those files. At least you have documentation of what you did,so you can undo it. I'd suggest using the commands in my comment above in the future rather than editing at the kernel level and using sites like wiki.cchtml.com or help.ubuntu.com